# How to save image to Photo gallery using JavaScript/Obj-C on iPad?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm currently developing a small, JavaScript based drawing application on iPad. I've simply wrapped it inside UIWebView like [this](http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/). Now the thing is that I can't figure out how to save an image from the app so that it's stored on iPad photos.

Is there some simple way to bridge JavaScript code with Objective-C one? I guess I could pass a string containing PNG image data from the JS side and then use Objective-C to save it to the photo gallery somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to bridge javascript from a UIWebView to Obj-C code.

Set your UIWebView delegate, and in your delegate paste in the following method

```
//
// Map links starting with file://
//            ending with #action
// with the action of the controller if it exists.
//
// Open other links in Safari.
- (BOOL)webView: (UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *fragment, *scheme;

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [webView stopLoading];
        fragment = [[request URL] fragment];
        scheme = [[request URL] scheme];

        if ([scheme isEqualToString: @"file"] && [self respondsToSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)]) {
            [self performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(fragment)];
            return NO;
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [request URL]];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Then you can write Obj-C methods that'll handle the request.  For example.  In your webview you might have a button that has a link tag like

```
<a href="file://myGreatApp.com/saveImage">Click Me to Save Image </a>
```

The scheme is "file" the fragment is "saveImage".  You can now write an Obj-C method

```
-(void)saveImage;
```

That will be called every time a user clicks on the link.

**Edit:**
If you want to pass string parameters in your method, simply append them to your fragment url using javascript.  So instead you might have

```
<a href="file://myGreatApp.com/saveImage*asdgo8asdgl35lkjasgd807ll12">Click Me to Save Image </a>
```

Then in your Obj-C code, split the fragment on the char '*'.  Use the first half as your selector and the second half as the parameter.

Comment: Any idea how to pass the data (just a string really) from the JS app to Obj-C? I might be missing the point here. Thanks for the answer, though. :)

Comment: Use a char separator and append it to your fragment.  So use javascript to dynamically make your link href file://myGreatApp.com/saveImage*imgdataimgdataimgdataimgdata.  Then in the obj c code, you'd split fragment by '*'.  The first half becomes your selector 'saveImage' while the second half becomes the string object you pass in the selector.

Comment: I ended up using this solution, http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript .